# How to create ActiveX TextBox dynamically on PowerPoint

Tags: vba, textbox, powerpoint, activex

I am a free-lance Java programmer who, for the first time, is asked to do some VBA programming on PowerPoint and I am struggling a bit.

I have created a button, which triggers the creation of a slide (this works).
On this new slide, I want to create an ActiveX TextBox (one of those that work when in Presentation mode), but I am only able to create "stardard" PowerPoint textboxes.

I am sure this is a quite easy command, but I cannot find it anywhere..

This is the code that I am using. Can somebody help me?
Thank you!

```
Public Sub addContentToSatelliteSlide()
currentSlide = ActivePresentation.SlideShowWindow.View.Slide.SlideIndex 
'CURRENT SLIDE ON SLIDESHOW

With ActivePresentation.Slides(currentSlide + 1).Shapes
    With .AddTextbox(msoTextOrientationHorizontal, 160, 80, 400, 400).TextFrame
        .TextRange.Text = "add informatiom here"
        .TextRange.Paragraphs.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = ppAlignLeft
        .TextRange.Font.Color = RGB(255, 255, 255)
        .TextRange.Font.Size = 11
        .TextRange.Font.Name = "Arial"
        .TextRange.Font.Bold = False
        .TextRange.Font.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0)    'BLACK
    End With 
End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

An ActiveX text box is an OLE control, so use this syntax instead:

```
.AddOLEObject Left:=160, Top:=80, Width:=400, Height:=400, ClassName:="Forms.TextBox.1"
```

Here's the Microsoft help page for this: [Shapes.AddOLEObject method (PowerPoint)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/powerpoint.shapes.addoleobject)